# Excel macro that suspends Application.Calculation breaks Save As menu

Tags: excel, vba

I am experiencing baffling behavior with an Excel macro running in Office 365 that I have reduced to the following block.  The Excel process becomes corrupted if:

1. `Sheet1!A1:A1000` are filled with letters (just `"A"` is sufficient).  This is to create a sufficiently large computation load in the macro.  Too little load and it doesn't break things.
2. A formula references something that will be altered by the macro.  E.g., set `Sheet1!B1` formula to `=ISNUMBER(E1)`.
3. The `TestMacro()` below is invoked from *within* the VBA editor (using `F5`).

(Omit any of these test conditions and the behavior described below does not occur.  However with more complex sheets it occurs much more easily, including not requiring the macro be invoked from within the VBA editor.)

```
Sub TestMacro()

    On Error GoTo EH

    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    row = 1
    col = 5

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(row, 1).Value)
        Cells(1, col).Value = Cells(row, 1).Value & " col"
        Cells(3, col).FormulaR1C1 = "test" & Cells(1, col).Value
        Range("E2:K2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Cells(2, col).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        col = col + 8
        row = row + 1
    Loop

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

EH:
    ' Do error handling
    GoTo CleanUp
End Sub
```

The symptom I check to see whether the macro has messed up Excel is to go to `File >> Save As` and when things are not right I get a blank dialog screen like this:

[image: Blank Save As dialog]

Further testing shows that if I omit the two lines in `TestMacro` that suspend and then resume `Application.Calculation` then no problems arise.

I have tried putting a simple `DoEvents` call immediately before `Exit Sub` but that puts the Excel instance into a state in which the cursor perpetually flits rapidly between normal and Wait.

I suspect there is something structurally incorrect in this VBA subroutine structure, but it is tricky to reveal, and I can't begin to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Code is working for me and _Save As_ dialog is not "meesed up".

Comment: @Storax Yes the code works great until it doesn't.  Please try to increase the workload in the `Do While` loop until you encounter the problem.  E.g., have it set a calculation formula in each cell for a range of hundreds or thousands of cells. 
 And be sure you're running latest Office 365.

Comment: I, too, cannot reproduce your problem. Even with the code filling every cell out to XFD2 and XFD4. Perhaps you could post something that reproduces the problem at your end.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I spent two hours to produce a relatively simple but sufficient example to reproduces this.  I just updated the question with it.  I would be grateful if you took another look!

Comment: @Storax Please have a look at the detailed steps I added to reproduce the problem.

Comment: After setting up columns A & B as you described, I ran the macro and reproduced your described problem. **In addition** I then closed/saved the file as an `*.xlsm` file to my OneDrive and tried to re-open it. I received two error messages: `READ-ONLY We opend this workbook read-only from the server` and `FILE IN USE  This file is locked for editing by another user`. **but that user was ME!!**.  These warnings persisted even after rebooting my computer. I think you should report this to MS (along with the procedure to reproduce)  via **Feedback** (from the File tab/page).

Comment: Yes, I was also able to reproduce the problem but as soon as I replace these four lines `Range("E2:K2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Cells(2, col).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False` with proper code the issue did not occur.

Comment: After a while, I was notified that the workbook was now available for editing.  I was able to edit it, and the Save As page returned to normal.  Some kind of weird timing problem where it became possible to access the Save As page before all of the calculations had finished?  perhaps?

Comment: @Storax can you post a answer explaining what is wrong with that code block?

Comment: Not really wrong but because you use `select`  and `Selection` etc. it is very slow. If you replace this with code you would normally use the problem disaapears. My guess is it has something to do with the intensive use of `Copy` and `Paste`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, it appears it's stuck in some sort of extended calculation loop.  This can be seen if you put `DoEvents` right at the end of the macro.  Which makes me suspect that either I am misusing VBA or else this has exposed a true bug?

Comment: @Storax I see: So this was a trick to get the "sufficient load" necessary to show the problem with a relatively simple example.  The problem's occurrence is very sensitive to the load invoked within the macro.

Comment: Hmm, I was able to reproduce the problem with the following code     `Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A1:B1")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To 1000 Step 2
        rg.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Cells(1, i)
    Next i` Sheet set up in the same way as in your post.